# When I am bootstrapping a node, I'm getting this error:

Tags: linux, devops, chef-infra, bootstrapping, chef-client

When I am bootstrapping a node, I'm getting this error:
/opt/chef/embedded/bin/ruby; error while loading shared libraries: libcrypt.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

I executed below command
knife bootstrap 172.31.6.156 --ssh-user ec2-user --sudo -i key-node1.pem -N node1

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

It's telling you that you need to install libcrypt.so.

You can check with `ldd $(type -p chef)` which lists the shared libraries needed by chef. Since chef makes use of functions in libcrypt.so, and you don't have it installed, Chef can't work.

On Ubuntu, one would find the package to install (to obtain libcrypt.so) with:

```
dpkg -S libcrypt.so
```

but you didn't let us know which distribution you're using.

If using Linux/AWS/Redhat, try this instead:

```
sudo yum update
sudo yum install glibc
```

Now search for library

```
find / -name "libcrypt.so.1" 2>/dev/null
```

If the find command shows nothing, this means "libcrypt.so.1" is still missing. Download and install it manually by,

```
yum provides "*/libcrypt.so.1"
yum install "*/libcrypt.so.1"
```

Reference:
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/746042/error-while-generating-cookbook-missing-shared-library-libcrypt-so-1